# Help me identify bike model by picture

Tags: mountain-bike, identify-this-bike

I have a friend which has a friend who is selling his bike, the only picture i have is this one bellow, i know it is a Focus bicycle but i don't know the model.

[image]

Comment: It may need work.   Is that a ruined rear brake cable or part of the background ?

Comment: @Criggie that's a roll of stuff hanging from the bar, the brakes are hydraulic, probably BR-M775.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paint job matches that of a Focus Raven 2008, not sure about the spec level as this info is hard to find without detailed catalogs and [the Focus archive](https://www.focus-bikes.com/int/archive#page=1) doesn't work for me. [Here's a product page](https://market.yandex.ru/product--gornyi-mtb-velosiped-focus-raven-2008/1635473) on Yandex aggregation service, the bike has the same paint scheme, albeit with different colors. [Here's a review](https://www.bike-magazin.de/mountainbikes/hardtail/focus-raven-extreme/a1275.html) that mentions the 2008 model and a similar paint scheme. [The 2009 model](https://market.yandex.ru/product--gornyi-mtb-velosiped-focus-raven-expert-2009/4714729) looks to have a different paint job.

Comment: Thank you kind sir!